# Make changes on the selected curve spline (Edit mode) using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have this curve that contain many splines. What I want to do is:

Select the curve -> Edit mode -> select one or more splines --> delete it using geometry nodes.

Do geometry nodes can detect the currently selected spline?

[image]

Comment: Selection in gn is available when defining a "tool" gn tree. But these tools are available for meshes, not curves.